# Should I avoid using pointers here?

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers, std, stdmap

I have this simple code:

```
std::vector<std::map<double,double>> v;
//populate v

//we know each map already has correct key order (enforced by c++)
//but i also want to make sure the different maps have correct key order
//this is how I do it using a pointer:

const double *last_key = nullptr;
for (const auto &map : v)
{
  if (map.size() > 0) //ignore empty maps
  {
    if (last_key)
    {
      const auto &new_key = map.cbegin()->first;
      if (!(*last_key < new_key))
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid key order");
    }
    last_key = &(--map.cend())->first;
  }
}
```

Is this a good use for pointers? How would you do it instead?

The only real alternative I know (if I want to avoid pointers) is to do this:

```
double last_key;
bool last_key_has_been_set = false;
```

This works, but it requires that the key is default constructible and it involves unnecessary copying of keys (problem for different key types than `double`).

Comment: How about references instead? Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: @H2CO3 I thought about references, but can you assign new value to refs?

Comment: What you should use is the iterators themselves. They act as pointers.

Comment: Use `std::adjacent_find`. There are algorithms for a reason.

Comment: and how about iterators?

Comment: @nosid how does finding duplicates in a list help with this problem?

Comment: @Yakk: The version taking a predicate finds the first pair of adjacent elements where `predicate(first element, second element)` is true.

Comment: @celtschk ... still, the property roger.james is looking for isn't just about adjacent elements.  You'd have to both use a stateful predicate and have guarantees about order of evaluation, which `algorithm` rarely gives you.

Comment: @Yakk: If the empty sequences are removed, it actually is about adjacent elements, namely that the second one does not contain smaller elements smaller than those of the first one. And since there's nothing stateful in that condition and there's no change of the sequence (at the time the algorithm is called), there's also no dependence on the order of evaluation.

Comment: @celtschk so mix a filtering iterator with `!adjacent_find`?

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, that's exactly what I did in the second solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, since I now (think I) understand what your code is about, here's my take on it:

```
auto iter = v.begin();
auto end = v.end();
while (iter != end && iter->empty())
  ++iter;
if (iter != end)
{
  while (true) // loop and a half
  {
    auto next = iter+1; // at this point, we know iter != end
    while (next != end && next->empty())
      ++next;
    if (next == end)
      break;
    auto lhslast = lhs.end();
    --lhslast;
    if (lhslast->first > next->begin()->first)
      throw std::runtime_error("invalid key order");
    iter = next;
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

The code above can be further improved using another algorithm:

Replace

```
while (iter != end && iter->empty())
  ++iter;
```

with

```
iter = std::find_if(iter, end,
                    [](std::map<double, double> const& m) { return m.empty(); });
```

and analogous for the `next` loop.

Another option is to notice that if it were not empty maps, you could just use `adjacent_find`. Therefore another option is to make use of Boost's `filter_iterator` to get rid of the empty maps. Thus do

```
#include <boost/iterator/filter_iterator.hpp>

struct is_not_empty
{
  template<typename Container> bool operator()(Container const& c) const
  {
    return !c.empty();
  }
};
```

and then at the place of your code

```
auto fbegin = boost::make_filter_iterator(is_not_empty(), v.begin(), v.end());
auto fend =  boost::make_filter_iterator(is_not_empty(), v.end(), v.end());

if (std::adjacent_find(fbegin, fend,
                       [](std::map<double, double> const& lhs,
                          std::map<double, double> const& rhs) -> bool
                       {
                         auto lhslast = lhs.end();
                         --lhslast;
                         return lhslast->first > rhs.begin()->first;
                       }) != fend)
  throw std::runtime_error("invalid key order");
```

The filter iterator makes sure that only the non-empty maps are considered.

Comment: What if the very first entry of the vector is an empty map?

Comment: @jogojapan: Please note that I've added a second solution

Comment: The `filter_iterator` solution is interesting. I just wish it supported lambda function instead of that is_not_empty struct.

Comment: There are syntax errors. Could you compile and correct the code? (By the way, interesting idea. I had upvoted your answer already, so I can't upvote it again...)

Comment: I'm sorry about the errors; they should be fixed now. Apart from trivial errors (typos and a missing const), the main problem was that `map` has no `front` and `back`; they have to be emulated with iterators (I also applied a corresponding fix to the first version). Also, I forgot to compare the result of `adjacent_find` with the end iterator.

Comment: I think this is by far the most elegant solution. I'll try this out soon.

Comment: @roger.james: Note that I just noticed that I forgot to copy a piece back from my editor, so there was still a bug in the code. But now it is (hopefully) correct.

Comment: `rbegin()` instead of `--end()` would make it prettier.  Another amusing thing would be writing `last_element<Container>` and `first_element<Container>` and using them as the args to your lambda

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a suitable predefined algorithm in the standard library that does this. In particular, `std::adjacent_find` *could* be used for this if you were to define a relatively complex and stateful predicate for it, but that would really amount to misusing `std::adjacent_find` as some kind of replacement for `std::for_each`, i.e. it would not have much to do with the original purpose of `std::adjacent_find`.

However, instead of naked pointers, you should be using iterators. I'd also suggest putting the checking code into a separate function, perhaps named `check`. Here is what I would suggest:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

bool check(const std::vector<std::map<double,double>> &v)
{
  /* Fast-forward to the first non-empty entry. */
  auto it = begin(v);
  for( ; it != end(v) ; ++it)
    if (!it->empty())
      break;

  /* We might be done by now. */
  if (it == end(v))
    return true;

  /* Else, go through the remaining entries,
     skipping empty maps. */
  auto prev = it->end();
  advance(prev,-1);
  ++it;

  for ( ; it != end(v) ; ++it)
    {
      if (!it->empty())
        {
          if (it->begin()->first < prev->first)
            return false;
          prev = it->end();
          advance(prev,-1);
        }
    }

  return true;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::map<double,double>> v;

  /* Two entries for the vector, invalid order. */    
  v.push_back({ {1.0,1.0} , {2.0,4.0} });
  v.push_back({ {3.0,9.0} , {1.0,16.0} });

  if (!check(v))
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid order of the maps in the vector.");

  return 0;
}
```

*Note:* It would be even more C++-like (or, at least more like the algorithms in the standard library) if you were to define the `check` function as an algorithm that takes a range of iterators, rather than a reference to a container, as argument. Rewriting the function to match this concept is straight-forward.

*Note 2:* The advantage of using iterators instead of naked pointers is that you get a better and cleaner abstraction of what you need: Something that references an item in the map, whereas a `double*` pointer *could* be pointing to all kinds of things. However, there is also a disadvantage of using iterators: If you were to modify your algorithm such that it alters maps while iterating through the vector, the iterator may be invalidated, whereas the pointer would not (unless you delete the element it points to). (The pointers might be invalidated if you alter the vector, though.)

But as long as the checking procedure is only used for checking and nothing else (which my code indicates by putting the code into a separate function dedicated to this purpose, and by taking the vector as a const-reference), iterator invalidation is not an issue.

Comment: You can prove that if you have a bad order, you **must** have a local adjacent bad order. That's why the use of `adjacent_find` does perfectly match the problem.

Comment: @lip The original purpose of `std::adjacent_find` is to find adjacent elements that are equal, not adjacent elements that are in bad order. I agree that, to some extent, it may be ok to misuse its original purpose by defining an equality-predicate that actually checks for the negation of less-than. But for this to deal with empty maps as well, you need to introduce state, and that means the predicate you need to define gets _very_ complex. It amounts to coding a very complex pseudo-equality predicate in order to get `std::adjacent_find` to do something it was not meant to do.

Comment: This looks equally complex to the original pointer solution. Do you agree that pointers should be avoided? Why?

Comment: @roger.james The algorithmic complexity is the same as before. The code is a bit longer, but that's not because of the iterators. I simply find the code easier to read this way.

Answer (score 0):

Best noted comment gives the answer : use `adjacent_find`.

First a little bit of logic. If there is n < m indexes verifying key[n] > key[m], then an index i exists, n <= i < m where key[i] > key[i+i].

You can demonstrate this with absurdity reasoning : If there is no such i, then for all i between n and m we have order, and because order relation is transitive, key[n] <= key[m] : absurd.
This means, ignoring the empty maps, if you have bad order on your keys, then you have two *adjacent* keys in bad order.

So your algorithm shoud be:

```
typedef map<double, double> map_t;
vector<map_t> v;
remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](map_t const& m){return m.empty();});
if(adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end(), [](map_t const& l, map_t const& r)
    {
        return (--l.cend())->first > r.cbegin()->first;
    }) != v.end())
    throw std::runtime_error("invalid key order");
```

This is, of course, if you *can* remove the empty maps from your vector first. (we can assume that, as empty maps may not be so meaningful, but it depends on the whole situation, for sure).

Comment: It's a vector of maps, not a vector of ints. This _does_ complicate the situation.

Comment: @jogojapan: Actually what complicates the situation is that the maps may be empty.

Comment: @celtschk Whereas ints cannot be empty, indeed.

Comment: Sorry, this was a little bit far, I edited the code to get closer match the actual problem.

Comment: But does this take into account invalid order of two maps that have an empty map between them?

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, we could go through a cleaned boundaries vector of pair of doubles first, but then the solution seems as complicated as having a custom algorithm... my bad ! I added a line to remove empty maps, but of course this solution stands only if you *can* remove them.

Comment: After the most recent edit, I still don't agree that `std::adjacent_find` is quite suitable, and it's also important to note that you latest fix involves removing empty entries (which changes the semantics of the original algorithm significantly). But it's not completely wrong, so I'll lift my downvote. (Minor note: You need a semicolon `;` after `return m.empty()` in the predicate for `remove_if`.)

Answer (score 0):

This uses a C++1y feature (`std::tr2::optional`), but should work with any container and any ordering on the elements of the containers:

```
struct compare_key_order {
  template<typename LHS, typename RHS>
  bool operator()( LHS const& lhs, RHS const& rhs ) {
    return lhs.first < rhs.first;
  }
};

template<typename ContainerOfContainers, typename Ordering>
bool are_container_endpoints_ordered( ContainerOfMaps&& meta, Ordering&& order=compare_key_order()  )
{
  using std::begin; using std::end;

  // or boost::optional:
  std::tr2::optional< decltype( begin(begin(meta)) ) > last_valid;

  for( auto&& Map : std::forward<Meta>(meta) ) {
    auto b = begin(Map);
    auto e = end(Map);
    if (b==e)
      continue;
    if (last_valid)
      if (!order( **last_valid, *b ))
        return false;
    last_valid = e;
  }
  return true;
}
```

`optional` is a prettier, less error prone way of dealing with the "this element may or may not exist" than a pointer-that-can-be-`nullptr`.  If you are using `boost` or have access to a `std::tr2::optional` (or you are reading this in the future, when `std::optional` exists), it is a better idea than a pointer.

You could also move the "is there a `last_valid` out of state and into program code location:

```
struct compare_key_order {
  template<typename LHS, typename RHS>
  bool operator()( LHS const& lhs, RHS const& rhs ) {
    return lhs.first < rhs.first;
  }
};

template<typename ContainerOfContainers, typename Ordering>
bool are_container_endpoints_ordered( ContainerOfMaps&& meta, Ordering&& order=compare_key_order()  )
{
  using std::begin; using std::end;

  auto it = begin(meta);
  while( it != end(meta) && (begin(*it) == end(*it)) {
    ++it;
  }
  if ( it == end(meta) )
    return true;
  auto last_valid_end = end(*it);
  for( ++it; it != end(meta); ++it ) {
    auto b = begin(*it);
    auto e = end(*it);
    if (b==e)
      continue;
    if (!order( *last_valid_end, *b ))
      return false;
    last_valid = e;
  }
  return true;
}
```

this would let the same algorithm run on vectors-of-vectors-of-pairs, or even check if vectors-of-vectors have sorted endpoints (with a different `order`).